# `EPIPE` error while testing POST request using Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a simple server which accepts `POST` requests and responds with the `413 Request entity too large` error if the request body exceeds allowed size. When I'm testing it using Jest the request sometimes returns correct error, but more often it returns `{ code: EPIPE, syscall: write }` error.

I tested server using cURL and from node javascript file and the server worked as expected, but Jest testing still gives me that error. I also tried another request libraries, they gave the same error.

```
beforeAll(() => {
  server.listen(testingPort);
});

afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});

describe("POST request", () => {
  test("should return error 413 in respense to exceeded file size", async () => {
    const fileContent = new Array(1024 * 1024 + 10).join("*");
    const fileName = "post-test-file.txt";
    const urlObj = new URL(fileName, host);

    try {
      await axios.post(urlObj.href, fileContent);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.code, e.errno, e.syscall); // EPIPE EPIPE write
      // expect(e.response.status).toBe(413);
    }
  });
```

Maybe you have any thoughts about this?

Comment: Make sure you use `https` instead of `http`, at least thats often the mistake i do which results in this error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is very old and not quite resolved:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/947

For me the workaround is using a stream.